# Find accounts innactive for X days in specific OUs

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory

I am trying to get a PowerShell script running that will display a list of all users who have been inactive (or not logged in) in x days.  That part was easy enough to find and modify a script for, but I am having trouble setting it so I can specify only certain OUs and sub OUs within the domain.  This is what I have so far, though I think I might have to use another method to accomplish this:

```
#Import Ad Module
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

#SearchBase
$searchB = (Get-Content -Path C:\scripts\ous.txt)

#Time accounts have been inactive
$tSpan = "145"

Search-ADAccount -SearchBase $searchB -AccountInactive -UserOnly -Timepsan $tSpan |
  Where {($_.DistinguishedName -notlike "specific sub-ou I don't want to check")} |
  FT name,ObjectClass -A
```

The text file is in the format:

```
OU=first ou,OU=Parent OU,DC= thisDC,DC=dc,DC=DC 
OU=third ou,OU=Parent OU,DC= this DC,DC=dc,DC=DC 
OU=fourthou,OU=Parent OU,DC= thisDC,DC=dc,DC=DC
```

When I run this I get an error

> Search-ADAccount : Directory object not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have a type mismatch in your `-SearchBase` parameter.

See `Get-Help Search-ADAccount`

Note that the value type for `-SearchBase` is `string`.  You have three OUs in your text file, so `Get-Content` on that file is going to produce a string array (`string[]`).

Since the `-SearchBase` parameter will only accept a single value, you'll need to `foreach` through the OU list, giving on one OU at a time:

```
foreach ($OU in $SearchB)
{
  search-adaccount -searchbase $OU -accountinactive -useronly -timepsan $tSpan.....
}
```

Comment: Awesome, that is pretty much was I was trying to figure out how to do! Thanks!